# cannot create triangle in shell script with for loop

Tags: shell, for-loop

I am quite new in shell script and trying to make some practice. What I want to do is to get an input from the user and create a triangle by using for loop. For example; if the user types 4 as input then the targeted triangle will be;

1

2
2

3
3
3

4
4
4
4

Here is my code:

```
num=4  ##Assume num is given by user##
for ((i=1; i<=$num; i++))
do
    for ((j=1; j<=i; j++))
    do
        echo $i
    done
    echo " "
done
```

Output:

1
22 
333 
4444

Is it something related with 'new line' thing? How can I fix it?
By the way, I am using an online shell terminal.
Thank you very much.

Comment: It's really hard to tell what you're asking when your target/actual results aren't in code tags.  (Normally it wouldn't matter, but whitespace seems important in this situation.)  Can you please [edit] your question so we can better understand the  target output and actual output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`echo $i` prints the value behind the `i` variable **and a newline**. You want to print a newline after all the numbers. Use `-n` switch.

```
num=4  ##Assume num is given by user##
for ((i = 1; i <= num; i++))
do
    for ((j = 1; j <= i; j++))
    do
        echo -n "$i "
    done
    echo
    echo
done
```

Or printf:

```
num=4  ##Assume num is given by user##
for ((i = 1; i <= num; i++))
do
    for ((j = 1; j <= i; j++))
    do
        printf "%s " "$i"
    done
    printf "\n\n"
done
```

1. Remember to qoute your variables (`echo "$i"` not `echo $i`)
2. No need to use `$num` inside `(( .. ))`. All names are expanded automagically.

@edit

On revisiting the question I came up with the following oneliner with the same functionality:

```
num=4
seq 1 "$num" | xargs -n1 seq -s ' ' 1
```

1. `seq 1 "$num"` generates numbers 1 2 .... $num separated by newlines
2. Then for each number `xargs` runs `seq -s ' ' 1 <number>` generating 1 .. number for each number separated by spaces
3. You can insert double newlines with `| sed 's/$/\n/'` if needed.